Select all rows as array of json objects for empty table
I have a query:
SELECT json_agg(t) FROM t

, which fails, when t table is empty. How to return no rows in this case?

How does in fail?  I get a row containing NULL.

You are right,  thanks. I wrongly interpreted the error from my db driver. I am deleting the question

To get no row if the table is empty, you can try this :
SELECT json_agg(t) 
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t)
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 0;


Looks good. I wonder, if it is possible to write it in a simpler way

You might be looking for
SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(t), '[]') FROM t

